# Gemfile.lock : Sidekiq Enterprise Gems Keep Moving Around

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

Recently we noticed that the sidekiq gems keep moving in our gemfile locks. This is new. No matter which way I check this in, it seems to come back on the next bundle install. Any pointers on this? I have been parsing [the github repo](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/5407) too without luck.

```
--- a/Gemfile.lock
+++ b/Gemfile.lock
@@ -47,8 +47,17 @@ GIT
       builder (>= 2.1.2)

 GEM
-  remote: https://rubygems.org/
   remote: https://enterprise.contribsys.com/
+  specs:
+    sidekiq-ent (2.3.0)
+      einhorn (>= 0.7.4)
+      sidekiq (>= 6.3.0)
+      sidekiq-pro (>= 5.3.0)
+    sidekiq-pro (5.3.0)
+      sidekiq (>= 6.3.0)
+
+GEM
+  remote: https://rubygems.org/
   specs:
     Ascii85 (1.0.3)
     CFPropertyList (2.3.6)
@@ -1002,12 +1011,6 @@ GEM
       connection_pool (>= 2.2.2)
       rack (~> 2.0)
       redis (>= 4.2.0)
-    sidekiq-ent (2.3.0)
-      einhorn (>= 0.7.4)
-      sidekiq (>= 6.3.0)
-      sidekiq-pro (>= 5.3.0)
-    sidekiq-pro (5.3.0)
-      sidekiq (>= 6.3.0)
     sidekiq-status (2.1.0)
       chronic_duration
       sidekiq (>= 5.0)
```

Comment: Regarding "come back on the next bundle install", on the same machine or on, for example, your co-worker's computer? Did you check for different `bundler` versions? How and where is the gem configured in the `Gemfile`?

Comment: Plus are there any issue with certain order of gems?

Usually I would put it on the rubocop ignore list...

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to bundler version `2.3.16` looks like it fixed the issue